# ImplicitConversion error when creating matrixes in Sverchok Scripted Node

Tags: scripting, sverchok

I am getting the `ImplicitConversionProhibited()` error when using a Matrix object created inside of the Scripted Node in Sverchok. Is there a way to use matrixes created in the ScriptedNode?

> ```
> Implicit conversion from socket type SvStringsSocket to socket type
> SvMatrixSocket is not supported for socket Matrix of node Matrix
> Out.001. Please use explicit conversion nodes.
> ```

The scripted node has the following script (so just a simple Matrix)

```
    '''out matrix s'''
    
    import mathutils
    import math
    
    matrix = mathutils.Matrix([(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)])
```

[image]

Comment: You have to generate Matrix socket in the SN node. `out matrix m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"""
out matrix m
"""

Double quotes not single quotes.
Check indentation too by turning on/activating the raise errors to tree level button in the node properties on the right side panel.